# LXD: Getting DHCP IP but no ping outside

Tags: 16.04, lxc, lxd

So I setup a clean VM in VirtualBox. I setup bridge devices as described by [several](https://bayton.org/docs/linux/lxd/lxd-zfs-and-bridged-networking-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) [tutorials.](https://www.simpleprecision.com/ubuntu-16-04-lxd-networking-simple-bridge/)
I create a VM, I get a DHCP address. But after that I got no ping from the container to any IP on the local network, let alone outside.
I can ping the VM from my host though.

So the question remains, what am I doing wrong? 
I'm running both host and VM Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with LXD 2.0.8:

```
   root@ubuntu:/home/test# cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enp0s3
root@ubuntu:/home/test# lxc profile list
default
docker
root@ubuntu:/home/test# lxc profile show default
config:
  environment.http_proxy: ""
  user.network_mode: ""
description: Default LXD profile
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
name: default
used_by: []
root@ubuntu:/home/test#

root@ubuntu:/home/test# lxc list
+------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| NAME |  STATE  |         IPV4          | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| u1   | RUNNING | 192.168.192.12 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+------+---------+-----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
```

Any help is appreciated, as I'm going completely nuts. Thanks!

Comment: Is your ethernet interface enp0s3 or eth0?

Comment: Is UFW enabled on either host or VM? If so, does `/etc/default/ufw` say `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"` or `"ACCEPT"`?

Comment: @chili555 enp0s3 on my host, eth0 on my VM.